# how to clear the browser cache on the application load without effecting pagination?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angular js application.

For the first time application is working fine, when we release a new build with new changes, when the user trying to access the page browser is still loading the old files new changes are showing in the browser, to load the new changes user has to clear the cache and reload the application.

Is there any way to clear the browser cache on the application load.

I am clearing the cache like below.

```
function run($rootScope,$state, $stateParams, authorization, principal,$templateCache) {

//code to clear the cache.....
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
  });

}
```

it is clearing the cache, but pagination is not working after adding this code into application .

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The cache that is bothering you is not the template cache. The template cache is always empty when the application is loaded. The browser cache is not. Bundle the templates in the JavaScript bundle, or configure the server to send headers preventing the browser to cache the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set version for all of you *files* and `http` requests, **do not clear the cache!**

[Want to Browse Faster? Stop Clearing Your Browser Cache](https://www.howtogeek.com/184272/want-to-browse-faster-stop-clearing-your-browser-cache/)

how to set version to **files** and api **requests**, you can put a global variable to handle it after each publish for example:

```
var version = "1.0.0";

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.config(function(){
    //for routes
    //pages.html?v="+version 
    //controller.js?v="+version
})

app.controller("ctrl", function($http){
    $http.get("api/posts?v=" + version)
})
```

with this version you can handle your users browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, to solve this browser cache issues **you need to add some kind of unique identifier (hash/timestamp) to all your static files**.

There are lot of backend framework which bundles your file, optimize it and add a unique hash to it which gets changed after any change in the original file.

Tools varies depending upon the back-end framework you are using. This is the ideal approach for handling this issue.

You can check [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev), which is a really good library for re-visioning of your static assets.

To do it quickly, you can use an ***Interceptor*** on your main module, and append a version number to every request. You need to make sure that after every release you need to change the version number. **The downside of this approach is, even the file which has not be changed will get refreshed.**

```
yourModule.factory('cacheInterceptor', 
['$templateCache', '$window', function ($templateCache, $window) {
        var cacheInterceptor = {
            request: function (request) {
                if ($templateCache.get(request.url) === undefined) {  
                    var appVersion = '';
                        appVersion = $window.MyApp.appVersion;
                      request.url = request.url + '?appVersion=' + appVersion;
                }
                return request;
            }
        };
        return cacheInterceptor;
    }]);
```

**Note**: Version number you need to assign on the window object every time the application loads.

You can find more details on ***Interceptors*** in AngularJS [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)